# Adding elements after array used for linear probing is full

Tags: data-structures, hash, linear-probing

When the array used for linear probing hashing technique is full, can I add further elements ?

Comment: Doesn't "full" mean you can't? If you can, then it's not full.

Comment: I mean that when I use chaining method for hashing, even when the array is full, I can add the element at the end of Link List of any array element. Is something similar possible in probing method that I am unaware of ?

Comment: You can increase the size of the table providing that you re-hash everything in the table. That's very expensive, so you want the new size to be large enough so that it won't become full.